# PostgreSQL: relation does not exist (после использования WITH)

Tags: postgresql

Ребята, подсветите, пожалуйста, ошибку, а то сам не могу разобраться.

Вот у меня такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO target.table (
            collect_project_id,
            project_number,
            project_name,
            connect_project_id,
            project_desc,
            project_type,
            project_status,
            project_path,
            language_code,
            country_code,
            timezone,
            date_created,
            date_updated,
            edw_date_created
            )
            
WITH new_items AS
(SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified
FROM source.table),

exists_items AS
(SELECT collect_project_id
FROM target.table),

unique_items AS
(SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified
FROM new_items
WHERE new_items.id NOT IN (exists_items.collect_project_id))

SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified, getdate() AS edw_date_created
FROM unique_items;
```

Сейчас ругается, что relation "exists_items" does not exist. Но вроде бы ж я ее и создал?

При чем, что такой запрос

```
WITH exists_items AS
(SELECT collect_project_id
FROM target.table)
SELECT * FROM exists_items;
```

возвращает результаты.

Суть этого запроса такова, что мне необходимо добавить из source.table в  target.table все записи, которые ранее не были уже добавлены в target.table. Проверка идет по target.table.collect_project_id и source.table.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе, если подумать, то вполне логичная ошибка. Поэтому поменял запрос на такой:

```
WITH new_items AS
(SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified
FROM source.table), unique_items AS
(SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified
FROM new_items
WHERE new_items.id NOT IN (SELECT collect_project_id
FROM target.table))

SELECT * FROM unique_items;
```

И это работает так, как мне нужно.